# "rm" (delete) 8 million files in a directory?

Tags: linux, filesystems

I have 8 million files in my /tmp and I need to remove them. This server is also running pretty important app and I can not overload it.

```
$ ls | grep .| xargs rm
```

The above makes my app unresponsive.

Do you have any ideas how to remove these files? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @VladLazarenko Doesn't that still shell-expand `*`?

Comment: voting to reopen for migration to superuser.com

Comment: Also you shouldn't remove all the files in your /tmp/; some might be being used by running applications. You should track down the source of these temporary files, and fix it, and ensure that if that process hangs then there is cleanup code that will run, and in the future put those files in a folder in /tmp/.

Comment: try `rm . ` instead. This doesn't expand the filenames. And you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`.

Comment: How about `find /tmp -type f -delete`? Probably with `ionice`, from another comment. You may want to add other conditions to make sure you don't delete things that running programs still need.

Comment: What I want to know is how your filesystem was able to handle 8 million files in one directory in the first place...

Comment: I've removed 1 million files with php script with sleep(1) every 10000 interations in cycle. I was planning to run this script at night but my filesystem crashed, so I had to reinstall OS from scratch. That's my sad story.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/183821/rm-on-a-directory-with-millions-of-files covers this territory rather nicely, IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

Well yes, don't use ls (because it may sort files, and the file list may draw more memory than you would like), don't add pointless indirections like a pipe, or xargs.

```
find . -type f -delete
```

Comment: You are generally correct, but `ls` is a built-in in many shells.  The `-delete` option is only for GNU find, and it is generally aliased to `-exec /bin/rm -f '{}'` so it isn't clear whether your command is faster.  It is shorter to type, but that's not necessarily the performance metric requested.

Comment: It is not built-in in bash, csh, dash, ksh or zsh. It is built into command.com/cmd.exe called "dir" there; it is also built into sash, but it's called "-ls" there. In essence, it being a built-in is for the most part untrue.

Comment: As for GNU find, -delete uses unlinkat (at least on Linux) without going through the extra hoop of fork+execing rm.

Answer (score 1):

`grep .` is match anything, including nothing.

Cut it out of your chain to remove a process launched for each file.  That should speed things up nicely.

```
ls | xargs rm -rf
```

Note that this will choke on whitespace, so an improvement is

```
ls | xargs -I{} rm -v {}
```

Of course, a **much** faster method is to remove the directory and recreate it.  However, you do need to take care that your script doesn't get "lost" in the directory tree and remove stuff it shouldn't.

```
rm -rf dir
mkdir dir
```

Note that there are some subtle differences between removing all files, and removing and recreating the directory.  Removing all files will *only* remove visible files and directories; while removing the directory and recreating will remove all files and directories, *visible and hidden*.

Comment: Note that the much-liked `-1` flag isn't necessary if the `ls` detects its output is going to a pipe; ls will add that behaviour for you.

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
ls -1 | grep -v -e "ignoreFile" -e "ignoreFile2" | xargs rm -rf
```

`ls -1` is simplifying `ls | grep` .

`grep -v` will remove lines from the list. just give it any files that should not be deleted, separating patterns with -e flag

And just for a complete explaination:
(I'm guessing this is already known)
rm -rf :

```
-r recursive
-f force
```

Comment: `-1` in `ls -1 | grep` is useless. It is strictly equivalent to `ls | grep`